# Como colocar setas no grafico de uma curva paramétrica - Python - Plotly

Tags: python, matemática, gráfico, plotly

Eu postei essa mesma questão anteriormente no [stack overflow (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516221/adding-arrows-to-a-parametric-plot-python-plotly).

Sou novo em python e estou aprendendo a plotar funções paramétricas usando o plotpy.

Portanto, eu me "desafiei" a escrever um código que gera o gráfico paramétrico da curva γ:[-2π,2π] → R^2, γ(t)= (sin(t),t^2). Sendo assim, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True) 

x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 3000)

layout = go.Layout(
    title='$\gamma(t) = (\sin(t),t^2),\ t\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$',
    )

trace1= go.Scatter(
            x=np.sin(x),
            y=x**2,
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(
                shape='spline'
            )
        )

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1],layout=layout)
py.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image: The code works and this is the output]

Agora, gostaria de adicionar algumas setas neste gráfico, a fim de representar a direção do caminho que a curva γ está tomando. Ou seja, estou querendo gerar uma imagem semalhante a essa qui:

[image]

Procurei online sobre como fazer isso, mas até agora não encontrei nada.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Dá pra fazer sem problemas com o Plotly utilizando [multiple-annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#multiple-annotations), mas não é um código simples se você quiser que as setas apontem na direção da curva, pois será necessário calcular o ângulo para onde elas apontam.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer, obrigado pelo comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo e não respondendo à sua pergunta: tens que trabalhar com as ferramentas que o plotly te dá. Infelizmente esta biblioteca não tem suporte para seu requisito. Sugiro que dê uma boa olhada na documentação do Plotly e veja se algum outro gráfico consegue suprir suas necessidades.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: matplotlib.pyblot da suporte, da uma olhada

Comment: no matplotlib.pyplot eu sei fazer, eu queria fazer usando o ploply pq ele é mais "bonito". Obrigado pela resposta